# coded ui test select checkbox in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to define some Coded UI Tests with Visual Studio 2010. I need to select a checkbox in a JQGrid. The id of the elements are different in every session. Does anyone know how to obtain a handle to an element by class, or some other way of acheiving this?

Answer (score 1):

You use `SearchProperties`. Such as:

```
this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlType] = "Window";
this.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName, "WindowsForms10.Window", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));
```

This works for WinForms apps. I've never actually tried using Coded UI with a web app.